# Removing certain biomes when generating world in Bukkit/Spigot

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Is there a way of removing certain biomes (like Jungles) from the WorldCreator when generating a new world on the server? I'm trying to disable the biomes in only one world instead of all of them (which most of the examples online seem to be doing). Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own ChunkGenerator and override the methods generateExtBlockSections, generateBlockSections and generateChunkData. Now loop through all x and z in the chunk and get the supposed Biome from the [BiomeGrid](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/generator/ChunkGenerator.BiomeGrid.html). If the Biome is the one you would like to remove, replace it by a different Biome via [#setBiome](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/generator/ChunkGenerator.BiomeGrid.html#setBiome-int-int-org.bukkit.block.Biome-). With the manipulated BiomeGrid you can now call the super method.

I did not test this, but with this method I set the Biomes to ocean for the whole world in my SkyBlock plugin. So it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have made some progress by making a class which extends ChunkGenerator and did as you said. The only problem I'm having now is that teleporting any players to the new world will cause them to be teleported back to the main world. Does that mean that the world is not properly loaded or something?

Comment: The `ChunkGenerator` class does not implement the default world generation. Also, calling the super method `generateChunkData` throws an UnsupportedOperationException stating that the custom generator is missing an implementation.